# Format long number in Android

Tags: android, formatting

I encountered a problem in android, for example:

Number `78900000` will show `7.8E7` and not the number itself.

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#########.00");
dd2dec = new Double(df2.format(number).doubleValue());
```

How can I format the number and show it in original form without in scientific form ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might help:

```
format("%,d", (number)); //Displays with commas placed appropriately.

format("%,d", (number)); //Displays un-formatted integer.
```

[Android Formatting Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)